# Bitbucket Pipeline with MSDeploy.exe

Tags: .net, .net-core, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trialling bitbucket pipelines for CD, something I am quite new at, for my .NET Core 2.0 project. I am hosting it on a Windows web server configured for Web Deploy.

My typical deployment process is in Visual Studio where I use the Publish function and choose a Publish Profile - and that works fine.

So I took the command and added it to a BitBucket Pipeline and its a bit trickier than i thought. I am using the default template provide with some minor mods.

I see it is building based upon a .NET SDK image but it appears that MSDeploy.exe is not included OR the path is somehow wrong?

The pipeline yaml is below and the error is underneath that.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
# This is a sample build configuration for .NET Core.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/5Q4SMw for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - export PROJECT_NAME=TechsportiseOnline
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME
    - step:
        name: Deploy to Production
        deployment: Production
        # trigger: manual  # Uncomment to make this a manual deployment.
        script:
          - dotnet publish TechsportiseOnline/TechsportiseOnline.csproj -c Release /p:PublishProfile="Primary Host - Web Deploy" /p:Username="****" /p:Password="****"
```

Error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.814/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/build/netstandard1.0/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(170,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "%ProgramW6432%/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" is invalid. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/TechsportiseOnline/TechsportiseOnline.csproj]
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDeploy is windows only so not supported by the Linux based bitbucket pipelines.

The only alternative I have found is to use FTP, atlassian provide a pipe and example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[article](https://migueldelgadoangelo.medium.com/automate-net-core-deployments-to-windows-server-using-bitbucket-pipelines-50c78ca9ae54)

I found this quite helpful, sharing to help move this along.